# Reading an excel file in Java - Error

Tags: java, excel, runtime-error

I've been trying to write a simple Java in which the user could select an excel file and have the program spit out the string/numeric contents of the file.

I've come to what I thought was a viable program, but I got a massive error log when i tried it. The program is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class WriteExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

        String filename = selectedFile.getPath();
        System.out.println(filename);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        FormulaEvaluator fe = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        for(Row row : sheet){
            for(Cell cell : row){
                switch(fe.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType()){
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

The error log I receive is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:456)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:174)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:278)
    at WriteExcel.main(WriteExcel.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:50)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:84)
    ... 9 more
```

It was certainly a lot more error messages than I was anticipating. Can anyone point out my error (or share how to better optimize my code)? Thank you!

Comment: First of all, I would use a `FileFilter` as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html  The exception is thrown deep inside the constructor of `XSSFWorkbook`. Not sure, what's the cause but have you tried the other constructor: `new XSSFWorkbook(pathname);`